# screen shot from command line

Tags: command-line, cron, scripts

I am writing a sh file to take screen short and want to schedule in crontab
but when i run the .sh file it run OK no problem happens but when try to schedule it in crontab i got  an error like

```
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/366.
```

my .sh file is like

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='ABC'
import -window root $HOME/Desktop/$filename.png
```

any idea how to solve it i tried with

```
which import
```

it is showing

```
/usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could probably add this line before the import line

```
export DISPLAY=':0'
```

Comment: You can what existing 'displays' you are running on using `w`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a small software that can be useful for this task, allowing you some extra options, like delay between the screenshot and your command. It is called [scrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot).

I understand this is not your point here, but still can be a useful information for someone that google to here.